# What happens at the bottom of the monitor room in The Stanley Parable?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

When you enter the huge monitor room, run up the chair, onto the desk, and walk over the railing to fall down into the pit. Nothing happens once you land on the ground. There is one but nothing happened. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 12):

You are not supposed to be able to jump over the railing like that; it is simply a bug.  Nothing happens because the developer never anticipated that possibility.

[Edit] In the expanded [The Stanley Parable: Ultra Deluxe](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1703340/The_Stanley_Parable_Ultra_Deluxe/), instead of fixing this bug, the developer added a hilarious new ending when you trigger it. [Massive spoilers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjKdLHBLONg).

Comment: Maybe it's a "Bug ending" :)

Comment: it IS however a great way to get the speed run achievement. hit the button, climb up on the railing, and fall onto the catwalk as it ascends.

Answer (score -2):

I did that too. The only thing that happened was at the bottom, I pushed a bunch of random keys, and got an achievement called "You can't jump"

Comment: This doesn't seem to be tied to this location, though, and it probably was simply the moment the [requirements for the achievement](https://thestanleyparable.fandom.com/wiki/The_Stanley_Parable_Achievements) were met.